# Antonym of Hapax legomenon

Tags: antonyms

Aware that such a beast may not exist in the wild, I've painted myself into a corner in a naming scheme which now requires an antonym to **hapax legomenon**.

What is to be done?

Comment: Since *hapax legomenon* means "word used one time", perhaps something like *Polla legomenon* would suffice.  ("word used many times", theoretically.  You'd probably want to get a greek to translate properly.)

Comment: Would this question be self-referential because its answer might well be a _hapax legomenon_ itself?

Comment: A request for a possible neologism (in English, anyway) that stands in extreme opposition to a transliterated Greek term (ἅπαξ λεγόμενον) severely tests the boundaries of on-topicness at EL&U, in my opinion; it's not unlike seeking an antonym for _eidos_. The question presents an interesting puzzle, certainly, but the fact that comment-answerers have resorted to Greek in search of a suitable answer suggests that this is only marginally an English language question. (For a discussion of hapax legomenon, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon) on the subject.)

Comment: The odd thing about _hapax legomenon_ is that, although even so narrowly inclusive a reference work as _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ accepts it as an English term in good standing, that same dictionary does not treat either _hapax_ or _legomenon_ as English language words. Thus _hapax legomenon_ qualifies as English in a way similar to  _je ne sais quoi_, which likewise has an entry in the _Eleventh Collegiate_, although none of its component words do.

Comment: Would a word that's used twice count?

Comment: It would, but not exclusively. I think it was wikipedia had words for various numbers but not more-than-one in general. I've got hapax... vs napax... at the moment and will search-and-replace when the best answer comes in! :-)

Comment: From the Wikipedia article I cited above: "The related terms _dis legomenon_, _tris legomenon_, and _tetrakis legomenon_ respectively (/ˈdɪs/, /ˈtrɪs/, /ˈtɛtrəkɨs/) refer to double, triple, or quadruple occurrences, but are far less commonly used."

Comment: @Hugh : If you're inclined to post polla legonema etc as an answer,  I'll accept it.

Comment: @Hellion ditto for you (see above) if you're inclined to post polla legonema as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ***hapax legomenon*** means "word used one time", and has related terms *dis legomenon*, *tris legomenon*, and *tetrakis legomenon* for a word used 2, 3, and 4 times, respectively, perhaps something like ***Polla legomenon*** or ***pollakis legomenon*** would suffice.  (*Polla* = "many", so *pollakis legomenon* means "word used many times.")

Answer (score 2):

***"Run-of-the-Mill"*** matches it for balance, somewhat.

"widely used" "generic" are workaday solutions.

Google's response to run-of-the-mill is "About 32,500,000 results (0.55 seconds) " which seems apt.

Comment: ["Run-of-the-mill"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=run-of-the-mill&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en-GB&q=%22run-of-the-mill%22) only gets me about 3,480,000 results, so it's not as commonplace as ["commonplace"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22commonplace%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl), which gets about 15,200,000 results.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  More omnipresent definitely.

Comment: In this context (which is the naming of a category, rather than prose) the contrast to hapax, which will always be nearby, is probably more important than common usage. I'm worried about coining daft jargon, but polla should be memorable.

Comment: pollalegomena should mean many things said. When referring to people *hoi polloi* is a put down. *ta polla* -the majority of things- might work. Why not change languages and go for "Universalismus" ? I've no idea what it means but it is a real word.